# How to elegantly migrate from uses of `syscall.Syscall()`?

Tags: go

The [`syscall`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/) package is deprecated. Assume I have the following code which I would like to migrate to something that is not deprecated:

```golang
someGoObject := &struct{int; float32}{5, 45.4}
syscall.Syscall6(someProc.Addr(), 1, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(someGoObject)), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

whereby `someProc` is of type `*syscall.LazyProc` ([Windows](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/?GOOS=windows)).

The [sys subrepository](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/), which the `syscall` docs recommend to use instead, no longer offers a function akin to `syscall.Syscall`, and if the desired function is not implemented over there, one might attempt to solve the problem the following way, and believe the job is done:

```golang
someProc.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(someGoObject)))
```

whereby now `someProc` is of type [`*windows.LazyProc`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows#LazyProc).

However, if we did this, we would not get one of `syscall.Syscall`'s (and friends') guarantees, because `LazyProc.Call()` [is not implemented in assembly](https://go.googlesource.com/sys/+/77190671981848ff71219ecfff38636c9add3b79/windows/dll_windows.go#346):

> **(4) Conversion of a Pointer to a uintptr when calling syscall.Syscall.**
>
> The Syscall functions in package syscall pass their uintptr arguments
> directly to the operating system, which then may, depending on the
> details of the call, reinterpret some of them as pointers. That is,
> the system call implementation is implicitly converting certain
> arguments back from uintptr to pointer.
>
> If a pointer argument must be converted to uintptr for use as an
> argument, that conversion must appear in the call expression itself:
>
> ```golang
> syscall.Syscall(SYS_READ, uintptr(fd), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(p)), uintptr(n))
> ```
>
> The compiler handles a Pointer converted to a uintptr in
> the argument list of a call to a function implemented in assembly by
> arranging that the referenced allocated object, if any, is retained
> and not moved until the call completes, even though from the types
> alone it would appear that the object is no longer needed during the
> call.
>
> For the compiler to recognize this pattern, the conversion must appear
> in the argument list:
>
> ```golang
> // INVALID: uintptr cannot be stored in variable
> // before implicit conversion back to Pointer during system call.
> u := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(p))
> syscall.Syscall(SYS_READ, uintptr(fd), u, uintptr(n))
> ```

(Taken from https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/ )

The way I see it, the only way to be safe is to alloc the memory using C. However, this means we need to copy our data and increases the amount of code which needs to be written by quite a bit.

```golang
someObject := (*struct{int; float32})(C.calloc(1, unsafe.Sizeof(struct{int; float32}{}))) // Alloc
*someObject = struct{int; float32}{123, 456.789} // Fill with desired data
someProc.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(someObject))) // The actual call
C.free(unsafe.Pointer(someObject)) // Clean up
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way to handle this, is to use the [mkwinsyscall](//github.com/golang/sys/tree/master/windows/mkwinsyscall) tool.
You can create a Go file like this:

```
package main
//go:generate mkwinsyscall -output zmsi.go msi.go
//sys MsiOpenDatabase(dbPath string, persist int, db *windows.Handle) (e error) = msi.MsiOpenDatabaseW
```

Then run `go generate`, and you get a result file like this (some parts removed
for brevity):

```
func MsiOpenDatabase(dbPath string, persist int, db *windows.Handle) (e error) {
    var _p0 *uint16
    _p0, e = syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(dbPath)
    if e != nil {
        return
    }
    return _MsiOpenDatabase(_p0, persist, db)
}

func _MsiOpenDatabase(dbPath *uint16, persist int, db *windows.Handle) (e error) {
    r0, _, _ := syscall.Syscall(procMsiOpenDatabaseW.Addr(), 3, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(dbPath)), uintptr(persist), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(db)))
    if r0 != 0 {
        e = syscall.Errno(r0)
    }
    return
}
```

As you can see, it automatically takes care of the string conversion, as well
as the Syscall code, and even the error handling.