# Pass structure with pointers to go memory in C code

Tags: go, cgo

I'm relatively new in Go and studying how to operate with native API. Here is a particular example, need to verify that binary file is signed. For that, I want to use WinVerifyTrust windows API.

The problem:
WinVerifyTrust supplies WINTRUST_DATA structure which contains a pointer to WINTRUST_FILE_INFO which in order contains a pointer to a string =)

As we know it is forbidden to pass a pointer to the memory which contains pointers to other go memory in C or syscall.

But I just need to do that. What needs to be done?

Here is a package which wraps function above https://github.com/itchio/ox/blob/master/winox/verifytrust_windows.go they do that in a forbidden way

```
winTrustData.FileOrCatalogOrBlobOrSgnrOrCert = uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(fileData))

trustErr := syscallex.WinVerifyTrust(syscall.Handle(0), &policyGUID, winTrustData)
```

it is not allowed to store uintptr to go object in the intermediate variable before passing to syscall

What I want to do os next:

```
winTrustFileInfoMemory := C.malloc(unsafe.Sizeof(windows.WinTrustFileInfo{}))
if winTrustFileInfoMemory == nil {
    return errors.New("out of memory")
}
defer C.free(winTrustFileInfoMemory)

winTrustFileInfo := (*windows.WinTrustFileInfo)(unsafe.Pointer(winTrustFileInfoMemory))
winTrustFileInfo.Size = uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(windows.WinTrustFileInfo{}))
....
winTrustData.FileOrCatalogOrBlobOrSgnrOrCert = unsafe.Pointer(winTrustFileInfoMemory)
```

but it looks really ugly, do we have an ability to somehow pin the memory or something like it?

Comment: What you have done is the correct way to do it: allocate memory using C functions, make the call, then free that memory using C's `free()`. I encountered the same problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57979613/how-to-elegantly-migrate-from-uses-of-syscall-syscall where no good alternative has thus far been presented, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [the syscall docs](https://pkg.go.dev/syscall):

> Deprecated: this package is locked down. Callers should use the
> corresponding package in the golang.org/x/sys repository instead.

In your case, the corresponding function would be

```golang
func WinVerifyTrustEx(hwnd HWND, actionId *GUID, data *WinTrustData) (ret error)
```

Note the trailing "Ex" in the function name. Internally, this calls:

```golang
r0, _, _ := syscall.Syscall(procWinVerifyTrustEx.Addr(), 3, uintptr(hwnd), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(actionId)), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(data)))
```

So really, the pointer rule is now being broken by `sys/windows` instead of you. Sorry there's no better idea.
[see here for more](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows#WinVerifyTrustEx).